# Verify a RS256 jwt on node PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY failed

Tags: node.js, jwt, auth0, json-web-token

I'm trying to 
I'm trying to verify a `jwt` that use the `RS256` algorithm. When using the `hs256` algorithm everything works fine

```
let opts = {
  audience: 'y',
  issuer: `https://x.auth0.com/`,
  algorithms: ["RS256"]
}

jwt.verify(payload.token, 'secret', opts, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("invalid token in iamonline service " + err.message);
        return;
    }
```

I keep getting the error: `PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY failed`

While `auth0` has [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nodejs/03-authenticate-rs256) to do so, it assumes you are using express which I'm not. I am doing this over a websocket so no middleware.

The annoying bit is that `HS256` is fine for me but auth0 custom login forms seem to require `RS256`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`RS256` needs a public key to verify, but you are providing an string

```
jwt.verify(payload.token, 'secret', opts, (err, decoded) => {
```

See documentation of auth0

> **jwt.verify(token, secretOrPublicKey, [options, callback])**
>
> `token` is the JsonWebToken string
>
> `secretOrPublicKey` is a string or buffer containing either the secret for HMAC algorithms, or the PEM encoded public key for RSA and ECDSA.

You need to provide a PEM public key instead of `secret`. The PEM file content will start with `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`

```
var publicKey = fs.readFileSync('public.pem');
```

Comment: Yay, thanks! To add to this, in auth0 the file can be found in clients > advanced settings > certificates